# Build Android ICS Camera App native libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have cloned the code for the android camera app that comes with Android 4.0.
I am trying to build the native Mosaic JNI library required to run the Panorama Mode, but it is throwing an error connected to the OpenGL parameters it is using. its not a single error but rather something like:

jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp
:664: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'

etc..

Can anybody help me with this issue? do i need the complete source code of android to build this library?
If anyone has any experience with this please can you give me some pointers?

Thanks,

**UPDATED:**

I have tried another approach and i have managed to extract the compiled libjni_mosaic.so file.

Now i have an issue in adding compiled native code to an existing application as a library.
Can anyone give me some pointers on how to add the library?

Comment: The projects in the Android source code are only designed to be built as part of building a complete firmware image.

Comment: OK but this doesn't mean that it can't be build separately? i am looking a couple of android apps on the market that have done the exact same thing i am trying to do. so it must be possible right? so the question is how do i proceed? are you saying i can build it against the platform? any more pointers on this please?

Comment: Generally, Android source code projects cannot be built separately without varying amounts of work. Native libraries, in particular, may well use things that are outside of what is supported by the NDK. "how do i proceed?" -- learn how to use `grep`. Find where `glBindFramebuffer` lives. Figure out how you can copy that code into your hacked project. Lather, rinse, repeat. Whether or not you can come up with something usable in the end, I can't say. "so it must be possible right?" -- you would have to ask those developers how they did it.

Comment: @DArkO did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108603/ndk-error-trying-to-build-cyanogenmod-camera-application

Comment: No i haven't. but i know the code needs to be built with the android source code. Hope this info helps somehow.