# NDK error trying to build CyanogenMod camera application

Tags: android, android-ndk

A follow up question to an earlier one - [compile ICS/JB camera application - native library jni-mosaic error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069056/compile-ics-jb-camera-application-native-library-jni-mosaic-error)

I've been trying to build the ICS camera application from [CyanogenMod sources](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Camera).
I'm on Windows 7, UAC off. Using Cygwin and latest Android NDK.

Tried the chmod -R 777 on the workspace, added the `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.4.3` and `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog` to my **Android.mk** file but no matter what I do, I still get this error:

```
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= feature_mos_jni.cpp
In file included from jni/feature_mos_jni.cpp:21:0:
C:/android-ndk/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:592:13: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp
In file included from jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:19:0:
C:/android-ndk/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:592:13: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= trsMatrix.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= AlignFeatures.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= Blend.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= Delaunay.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= ImageUtils.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= Mosaic.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= Pyramid.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= Renderer.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= WarpRenderer.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= YVURenderer.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= FrameBuffer.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_feature_detection.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_feature_matching.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_framestitching.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_image_homography.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_rob_image_homography.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_utilities.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_utilities_camera.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_utilities_indexing.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_utilities_linalg.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= db_utilities_poly.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= dbreg.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : jni_mosaic <= dbstabsmooth.cpp
Compile thumb  : jni_mosaic <= vp_motionmodel.c
SharedLibrary  : libjni_mosaic.so
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/mosaic_renderer_jni.o: In function `checkGLErrorDetail(char const*, int, char const*)':
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:195: undefined reference to `glGetError'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/mosaic_renderer_jni.o: In function `checkFramebufferStatus(char const*)':
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:177: undefined reference to `glCheckFramebufferStatus'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/mosaic_renderer_jni.o: In function `bindSurfaceTexture(unsigned int)':
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:211: undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:215: undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:217: undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:220: undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:222: undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/mosaic_renderer_jni.o: In function `Java_com_android_camera_MosaicRenderer_init':
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:528: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:530: undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/mosaic_renderer_jni.o: In function `Java_com_android_camera_MosaicRenderer_transferGPUtoCPU':
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:695: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:703: undefined reference to `glReadPixels'
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:708: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
D:\CMCam/jni/mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp:716: undefined reference to `glReadPixels'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.o: In function `Renderer::loadShader(unsigned int, char const*)':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:39: undefined reference to `glCreateShader'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:41: undefined reference to `glShaderSource'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:42: undefined reference to `glCompileShader'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:44: undefined reference to `glGetShaderiv'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:47: undefined reference to `glGetShaderiv'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:51: undefined reference to `glGetShaderInfoLog'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:56: undefined reference to `glDeleteShader'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.o: In function `Renderer::createProgram(char const*, char const*)':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:78: undefined reference to `glCreateProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:81: undefined reference to `glAttachShader'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:83: undefined reference to `glAttachShader'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:86: undefined reference to `glLinkProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:88: undefined reference to `glGetProgramiv'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:95: undefined reference to `glGetProgramiv'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:106: undefined reference to `glDeleteProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:101: undefined reference to `glGetProgramInfoLog'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.o: In function `Renderer::SetupGraphics(int, int)':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:126: undefined reference to `glUseProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:129: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:135: undefined reference to `glViewport'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.o: In function `Renderer::SetupGraphics(FrameBuffer*)':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:157: undefined reference to `glUseProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:160: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:166: undefined reference to `glViewport'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.o: In function `Renderer::Clear(float, float, float, float)':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:185: undefined reference to `glClearColor'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/Renderer.cpp:186: undefined reference to `glClear'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.o: In function `WarpRenderer::InitializeGLProgram()':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:101: undefined reference to `glDeleteProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:82: undefined reference to `glUseProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:86: undefined reference to `glGetAttribLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:87: undefined reference to `glGetUniformLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:88: undefined reference to `glGetUniformLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:89: undefined reference to `glGetUniformLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:90: undefined reference to `glGetAttribLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:93: undefined reference to `glGetUniformLocation'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.o: In function `WarpRenderer::DrawTexture(float*)':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:119: undefined reference to `glDisable'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:121: undefined reference to `glActiveTexture'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:125: undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:129: undefined reference to `glUniform1i'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:133: undefined reference to `glVertexAttribPointer'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:137: undefined reference to `glVertexAttribPointer'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:139: undefined reference to `glEnableVertexAttribArray'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:140: undefined reference to `glEnableVertexAttribArray'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:143: undefined reference to `glUniformMatrix4fv'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:144: undefined reference to `glUniformMatrix4fv'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:145: undefined reference to `glUniformMatrix4fv'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:148: undefined reference to `glDrawElements'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/WarpRenderer.cpp:152: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.o: In function `SurfaceTextureRenderer::InitializeGLProgram()':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:110: undefined reference to `glDeleteProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:92: undefined reference to `glUseProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:95: undefined reference to `glGetAttribLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:97: undefined reference to `glGetAttribLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:99: undefined reference to `glGetUniformLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:101: undefined reference to `glGetUniformLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:103: undefined reference to `glPixelStorei'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.o: In function `SurfaceTextureRenderer::DrawTexture(float*)':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:128: undefined reference to `glDisable'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:130: undefined reference to `glActiveTexture'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:134: undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:137: undefined reference to `glUniformMatrix4fv'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:138: undefined reference to `glUniformMatrix4fv'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:142: undefined reference to `glVertexAttribPointer'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:143: undefined reference to `glEnableVertexAttribArray'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:146: undefined reference to `glVertexAttribPointer'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:147: undefined reference to `glEnableVertexAttribArray'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:150: undefined reference to `glDrawElements'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/SurfaceTextureRenderer.cpp:152: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.o: In function `YVURenderer::InitializeGLProgram()':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:70: undefined reference to `glDeleteProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:54: undefined reference to `glUseProgram'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:58: undefined reference to `glGetAttribLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:59: undefined reference to `glGetAttribLocation'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:62: undefined reference to `glGetUniformLocation'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.o: In function `YVURenderer::DrawTexture()':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:88: undefined reference to `glDisable'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:90: undefined reference to `glActiveTexture'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:94: undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:98: undefined reference to `glUniform1i'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:102: undefined reference to `glVertexAttribPointer'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:106: undefined reference to `glVertexAttribPointer'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:108: undefined reference to `glEnableVertexAttribArray'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:109: undefined reference to `glEnableVertexAttribArray'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:112: undefined reference to `glDrawElements'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/YVURenderer.cpp:116: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.o: In function `FrameBuffer::CreateBuffers()':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:72: undefined reference to `glGenFramebuffers'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:73: undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs/jni_mosaic/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.o: In function `FrameBuffer::Init(int, int, unsigned int)':
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:30: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:31: undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:41: undefined reference to `glTexImage2D'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:45: undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:46: undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:49: undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:50: undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:57: undefined reference to `glFramebufferTexture2D'
D:\CMCam/jni/feature_mos/src/mosaic_renderer/FrameBuffer.cpp:67: undefined reference to `glBindFramebuffer'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk/build/core/build-binary.mk:378: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/libjni_mosaic.so' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libjni_mosaic.so] Error 1
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: What do you have in `$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib`?

Comment: @AlexCohn nothing I'm aware of :) changed to LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog. I'm new to this so I'm not quite sure whether I need to edit the code written by Google. I understand that the main issue is I'm missing GLES2 libraries but have no idea where to find them/how to add them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand better how NDK interprets your `Android.mk`, you can run

```
ndk-build V=1
```

This will echo all executed commands, including compilation and link, with all their parameters that NDK build assigns.

Usually, NDK will include the directory `C:/android-ndk/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/`. If this path for any reason is not specified on the link command line (see **V=1** above), you should add it to `LOCAL_LDLIBS` manually.

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += C:/android-ndk/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib
```

The make file in cyanogen tree is not prepared for `ndk-build`. Instead of using the prebuilt system libraries that are packaged in NDK, it references libraries that it expects to be built during the `lunch` or `brunch`. This is why it has the line

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libnativehelper libGLESv2
```

You don't build the tree; therefore, these libraries are not local. But nevertheless, you must supply all three of them to the linker:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lnativehelper -lGLESv2
```

Unfortunately, only two are delivered with NDK. `libnativehelper.so` is not part of the public API. This means that in theory, you should not rely on it. In practice, though, this library is present on all devices, and its interface is pretty stable.

You can extract this binary file from your device, or even from an emulator using command

```
adb pull /system/lib/libnativehelper.so C:/android-ndk/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me again and with such detailed reply! worked like a charm... but the main thing, I really learned a lot here! Thanks again :)